# Python compare and count row values

Tags: python, pandas, count, compare

I'd like to compare two columns row by row and count when a specific value in each row is not correct. For instance:

```
group       landing_page 
control     new_page
control     old_page
treatment   new_page
treatment   old_page
control     old_page
```

I'd like to count the number of times `treatment` is not equal to `new_page` or `control` is not equal to `old_page`. It could be the opposite too I guess, aka `treatment` is equal to `new_page`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas groupby to find the counts of group/landing page pairs.

Use groupby again to find the group counts.
To find the count of other landing pages within each group, subtract each
landing page count from the group count.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['control', 'control', 'treatment',
                             'treatment', 'control'],
                   'landing_page': ['new_page', 'old_page', 'new_page',
                                    'old_page', 'old_page']})

# find counts per pairing
df_out = df.groupby(['group', 'landing_page'])['landing_page'].count().to_frame() \
    .rename(columns={'landing_page': 'count'}).reset_index()
# find totals for groups
df_out['grp_total'] = df_out.groupby('group')['count'].transform('sum')
# find count not equal to landing page
df_out['inverse_count'] = df_out['grp_total'] - df_out['count']

print(df_out)

       group landing_page  count  grp_total  inverse_count
0    control     new_page      1          3              2
1    control     old_page      2          3              1
2  treatment     new_page      1          2              1
3  treatment     old_page      1          2              1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm selecting this as the answer because it's the most scalable without much memory like a for loop, the `df` I'm using is thousands of rows

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the [zip()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) function.

First, setup your inputs and counters:

```
group = ["control", "control", "treatment", "treatment", "control"]
landingPage = ["new_page", "old_page", "new_page", "old_page", "old_page"]

treatmentNotNew = 0
controlNotOld = 0
```

Then zip the two inputs you are comparing into an iterator of tuples:

```
zipped = zip(group, landingPage)
```

Now you can iterate over the tuple values a (group) and b (landing apge) while counting each time that `treatment != new_page` and `control != old_page`:

```
for a, b in zipped:
    if((a == "treatment") and (not b == "new_page")):
        treatmentNotNew += 1

    if((a == "control") and (not b == "old_page")):
        controlNotOld += 1
```

Finally, print your result!

```
print("treatmentNotNew = " + str(treatmentNotNew))
print("controlNotOld = " + str(controlNotOld))

>> treatmentNotNew = 1
>> controlNotOld = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new column with `map` that maps your desired output given the input. Then you can easily test if the new mapping column equals the landing_page column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['control', 'control', 'treatment', 'treatment', 'control'],
    'landing_page': ['old_page', 'old_page', 'new_page', 'old_page', 'new_page']
})

df['mapping'] = df.group.map({'control': 'old_page', 'treatment': 'new_page'})

(df['landing_page'] != df['mapping']).sum()
# 2
```